# When can we multiply matrices to both sides of a equation?

Tags: matrices

So this question was recently asked in my exam

If A and B are two square matrices of same order such that 
 $AB=A$ and $BA=B$ then $A^2=?$

Here's what I did

As $$AB=A$$ $$\implies A^{-1}AB=A^{-1}A $$ (pre multiplying by $A^{-1}$) $$ \implies I B = I $$ or $$B=I$$

Here I is identity matrix of same order as A or B.

Similarly we can have from second equation $$A=I$$

Thus it follows $$A^2 = I^2 =I$$

So$$A^2 = I$$

But this was considered wrong and the correct answer was given as A as: $$A^2 = AA$$ $$\implies A^2 = (AB)(A) $$ As  $AB=A$  $$\implies A^2 = A(BA) $$ 
$$\implies A^2 = A B $$ As  $BA=B$ 
$$\implies A^2 = A $$ As $AB=A$

So $$A^2 = A$$

**My question:**

Why was my response considered wrong when actually both the answers are equivalent as $A= I$ ? Are they correct in saying my answer is wrong?

Comment: You cannot assume that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: What if it is?  Then am I correct?

Comment: @HrishabhNayal If it is, yes. But it need not be. What if it's the null matrix of that order?

Comment: If is a null matrix shouldn't $A^2$ be zero ? and not A

Comment: The answers aren’t equivalent: $A^2=A$ does not imply that $A=I$. Every projection satisfies this identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have shown is that if $A$ is invertible, then $A=I$.

However, $A$ need not be invertible.

For example, it is possible that $A=B=0$.  So yes, they are right to say that your answer is wrong.

You can multiply matrices of compatible size to both size if it exists.

Comment: Can you give an example of non invertible matrix where my answer would fail? And thanks for the answer.

Comment: $A=B=0$ is an example

Comment: Any non null matrix?

Comment: Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}=B$